# Multivariable Calculus - Change of Bound Help!

Tags: multivariable-calculus, upper-lower-bounds, bounds-of-integration

I am having trouble following these steps in a reading on multivariable calculus.

```
Due to a change of variables:
```

$ \displaystyle\int_t^T \int_t^s \theta_v dv \, ds = \int_t^T \int_s^T \theta_s dv \, ds$

Could anyone explain how you get the right equation? What is the 'change of variable' that is applied? Thanks!!

Also $t \leq T$ is given and theta is an arbitrary function.

Comment: Use the substitution $t=\frac{(v-s)(s-T)}{t-s}+T$

Comment: @PeterForeman can you explain that a bit more?

Comment: That is the only substitution I can think of that allows the bounds to change in such a way.

Comment: @PeterForeman do you know how this lets you "replace" theta(v) with theta(s)? Unfortunately I'm still confused here

Comment: Well since $\theta$ is an arbitrary function it doesn't matter